# In set builder notation, must the predicate have only one free variable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

question about set theory here, probably quite elementary.

When we use the notation $t\in\{x \mid \Phi(x) \}$, whether in an actual set theory or just as an abbreviation for $\Phi (t)$, must it be the case that the only free variable in $\Phi$ is $x$?

If not, what is the notation supposed to mean in the case that $\Phi$ has other free variables?

Comment: What does it mean in the case that $\varphi$ has other free variables? They act as *parameters*; consider: $E_y = \{ x | \varphi (x,y) \}$ : for every $y$ we have a different set $E_y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\Phi$ has other free variables... then $\{ x \mid \Phi \}$ is *still* the unique term with the property that $t \in \{ x \mid \Phi \}$ if and only if $\Phi[t/x]$. (assuming $x$ does not appear in the term $t$)