# Notation for Logic and Set Theory (Possible Semantic Consequence)

Tags: logic

I was wanting to get a better understanding for set builder notation when I came across this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873823/in-set-builder-notation-must-the-predicate-have-only-one-free-variable) asked awhile ago. What does $\Phi[t/x]$
 mean? I think it has something to do with a semantic consequence ($\models$) but could be wrong. I am pretty familiar with using syntactic consequences ($\vdash$) and maybe someone could explain it to me that way as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe what you get if you substitute $t$ for $x$ in $\Phi$? Or maybe what you get if you substitute $x$ for $t$ in $\Phi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Phi[t/x]$ means to take the formula $\Phi$, and replace every occurrence of the variable $x$ with the term $t$. For example, if $\Phi$ is $x^2 \geq 0$, and $t$ is $y-3$, then $\Phi[t/x]$ is $(y-3)^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer which is exactly what I wanted. So in the case of the question I was looking at $t=x$ correct?

Comment: No, it is not. In the context of the question, t appears to be any element from the domain over which x ranges.

Comment: So if $\Phi$ was the statement $(y\in \mathbb{Z})\wedge (\exists x \in \mathbb{Z})[y=2x]$ and I was wanting to say if $\Phi [t/x]$, then $t\in \lbrace x \mid \Phi\rbrace$. What would the statement for $\Phi [t/x]$ be? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, the correct answer would be that $\Phi[t/x]$ is just $\Phi$; the thing is that you only substitute the occurrences of $x$ in $\Phi$ which are free, and the only time the variable $x$ appears in $\Phi$ is bound. Of course, bound variables are essentially dummies; $\Phi$ is almost exactly the same as $(y \in \mathbb Z) \land (\exists z \in \mathbb Z)[y = 2z]$, and then it is clear that $\Phi[t/x]$ should just be $\Phi$.